# Row editing by toggling Bootstrap Modal in Symfony 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently working on a project with **Symfony 4** and **Bootstrap 3**.

On a specific page, I'm generating an array containing one row for each ***Contact*** entity persisted in my DataBase. The creation of one of this entity is handled by a *Symfony generated form* within a BootStrap modal.
I'd like to edit a row (i.e. an object) by **clicking on it**, which would toggle the modal and fill the inputs with the data related to this Contact, and let me modify whatever I want to.

I know I'll have to use Ajax to do this but I'm a bit lost with how to implement it because I'm kind of a rookie :o

I would really appreciate any hint to do this ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery and 'friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle' you can load the edit page into the popup for that specific id.

```
$('#your-popup').load(Routing.generate('contact_edit_page_route', { id : id }));
```

If you don't have an edit page for a contact with this route yet, first create it.
Don't forget to add the options={"expose"=true} to the route so Jquery can find it:

```
/*
 * @Route("/contact/edit/{id}", name="contact_edit_page_route", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
```

If the html looks like this:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    <a data-id="{{ contact.id }}" class="load-popup">Edit</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can do the following in the javascript:

```
$('.load-popup').on('click', function(){
    var thisId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#your-popup').load(Routing.generate('contact_edit_page_route', { id : thisId }));
});
```

Comment: Ah yes indeed friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle. In 99% of our projects it is included